# Strange behaviour because of the order of URLs in urls.py django behaviour

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am doing a mini blog assignment using Django for learning purpose. I noticed a strange behavior in django urls.py
when the order of lines is below I am able to make a successful GET call to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blog/create

```
path('blog/create', views.BlogPostCreate.as_view(), name='blogpost-create'),
path('blog/<slug:slug>', views.BlogPostDetail.as_view(), name='blogpost-detail'),
```

but when the above lines are reveresed Then I start getting 404 error.
[image: Error raised during GET]

I am not sure why this error is happening. By just reading the Raised By in the message I did some shot in the air and the create form start loading. Can anyone explain the behavior? I am sure there must be some explanation for this.

Comment: Because `create` is a fine _slug_. BlogPostDetail view raises 404 exception when tries to find record in the database with `slug="create"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the paths are checked one by one, if you work with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'blog/<slug:slug>', views.BlogPostDetail.as_view(), name='blogpost-detail'
    ),
    path('blog/create', views.BlogPostCreate.as_view(), name='blogpost-create'),
]
```

it will indeed pick the `BlogPostsDetail` view. Why? Because `create` is a valid slug. It thus will "*fire*" the `BlogPostDetail` view with `slug='create'`. Since there is no `BlogPost` with that slug, the view returns a 404.

But the URL *dispatcher* thus will enumerate over the patterns and fire the first one it finds that can fire. Since for `blog/create`, the first path can fire, it will pick that one. The fact that there is another path that can fire makes not much sense.

That being said, personally I'm *not* a fan of paths that can overlap. You might want to make non-overlapping ones, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blogs/create/', views.BlogPostCreate.as_view(), name='blogpost-create'),
    path(
        'blog/<slug:slug>/', views.BlogPostDetail.as_view(), name='blogpost-detail'
    ),
]
```

That way it is possible that a blog with `create` as slug is picked, and people can also create `BlogPost`s.